# How to make an HTML element appear after a specific page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make the element `<div id="text">` appear after a loading screen: "Welcome in Shanghaied".

But I can't make it show.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Idk</title>
        <script src="skrypt.js"></script>       <!--Zaimportowanie javascriptu-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">    <!--Odwołanie do cssa-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="disappear">
            <div class="container">     <!--Div z napisem-->
                <div class="data">Welcome in Shanghaied</div>   <!--Tu wpisz tekst-->
            </div>
            <!--Rozpoczęcia javascriptu-->
            <script type="text/javascript">
                const text = baffle(".data");
                text.set({
                    characters : '▒▓░ >▒█▓▒▒ >█▓▒░ ██▒ ▒█/▒░ ▓░>> <▒▓ █▒▓░ █▒▓▓',
                    // szybkość, im większa tym wolniej
                    speed: 69
                    
                })
                text.start();
                //ilość znaków
                text.reveal(4201);
            </script>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div id="text">
                <p>Test for the Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

**Css**

```
html, body{
    margin: 0;              /* margines */
    padding: 0;             /* Padding */
    width: 100%;            /* Szerokość */
    height: 100vh;          /* Wysokość */
    background: #101010;    /* Kolor tła */
    cursor: none;           /* Chowanie kursora */
}

.data{
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;    /* Po font family dajemy nazwe czcionki */
    color: #fff;            /* Kolor czcionki */
    font-size: 40px;        /* Rozmiar czcionki */
    letter-spacing: 12px;   /* Spacje pomiędzy literami */
    font-weight: 500;       /* Grubość czcionki */
    position: absolute;     /* Pozycja czcionki */
    top: 50%;               /* Pozycja czcionki */
    left:50%;               /* Pozycja czcionki */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.disappear {
    animation: disappear 0s linear 3.2s forwards;
}

@keyframes disappear {
    to {opacity:0;}
}

#text p {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    animation: appear 2s;
    left: 315px;
}
@keyframes appear {
    from {
        left: -100px;
    }
    to {
        left: 315px;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes appear {
    /* Firefox */
    from {
        left: -100px;
    }
    to {
        left: 315px;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes appear {
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        left: -100px;
    }
    to {
        left: 315px;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes appear {
    /* Opera */
    from {
        left: -100px;
    }
    to {
        left: 315px;
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
/*!
 * baffle 0.3.6 - A tiny javascript library for obfuscating and revealing text in DOM elements.
 * Copyright (c) 2016 Cam Wiegert <cam@camwiegert.com> - https://camwiegert.github.io/baffle
 * License: MIT
 */
!function(t,e){"object"==typeof exports&&"object"==typeof module?module.exports=e():"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define([],e):"object"==typeof exports?exports.baffle=e():t.baffle=e()}(this,function(){return function(t){function e(r){if(n[r])return n[r].exports;var i=n[r]={exports:{},id:r,loaded:!1};return t[r].call(i.exports,i,i.exports,e),i.loaded=!0,i.exports}var n={};return e.m=t,e.c=n,e.p="",e(0)}([function(t,e,n){"use strict";function r(t){return t&&t.__esModule?t:{"default":t}}var i=n(2),o=r(i);t.exports=o["default"]},function(t,e){"use strict";function n(t,e){for(var n in e)e.hasOwnProperty(n)&&(t[n]=e[n]);return t}function r(t,e){return t.split("").map(e).join("")}function i(t){return t[Math.floor(Math.random()*t.length)]}function o(t,e){for(var n=0,r=t.length;n<r;n++)e(t[n],n)}function u(t){return t.map(function(t,e){return!!t&&e}).filter(function(t){return t!==!1})}function s(t){return"string"==typeof t?[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(t)):[NodeList,HTMLCollection].some(function(e){return t instanceof e})?[].slice.call(t):t.nodeType?[t]:t}Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0}),e.extend=n,e.mapString=r,e.sample=i,e.each=o,e.getTruthyIndices=u,e.getElements=s},function(t,e,n){"use strict";function r(t){return t&&t.__esModule?t:{"default":t}}function i(t,e){if(!(t instanceof e))throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function")}Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0});var o=n(1),u=n(3),s=r(u),c={characters:"AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz~!@#$%^&*()-+=[]{}|;:,./<>?",exclude:[" "],speed:50},a=function(){function t(e,n){i(this,t),this.options=(0,o.extend)(Object.create(c),n),this.elements=(0,o.getElements)(e).map(s["default"]),this.running=!1}return t.prototype.once=function(){var t=this;return(0,o.each)(this.elements,function(e){return e.write(t.options.characters,t.options.exclude)}),this.running=!0,this},t.prototype.start=function(){var t=this;return clearInterval(this.interval),(0,o.each)(this.elements,function(t){return t.init()}),this.interval=setInterval(function(){return t.once()},this.options.speed),this.running=!0,this},t.prototype.stop=function(){return clearInterval(this.interval),this.running=!1,this},t.prototype.set=function(t){return(0,o.extend)(this.options,t),this.running&&this.start(),this},t.prototype.text=function(t){var e=this;return(0,o.each)(this.elements,function(n){n.text(t(n.value)),e.running||n.write()}),this},t.prototype.reveal=function(){var t=this,e=arguments.length<=0||void 0===arguments[0]?0:arguments[0],n=arguments.length<=1||void 0===arguments[1]?0:arguments[1],r=e/this.options.speed||1,i=function(){clearInterval(t.interval),t.running=!0,t.interval=setInterval(function(){var e=t.elements.filter(function(t){return!t.bitmap.every(function(t){return!t})});(0,o.each)(e,function(e){var n=Math.ceil(e.value.length/r);e.decay(n).write(t.options.characters,t.options.exclude)}),e.length||(t.stop(),(0,o.each)(t.elements,function(t){return t.init()}))},t.options.speed)};return setTimeout(i,n),this},t}();e["default"]=function(t,e){return new a(t,e)}},function(t,e,n){"use strict";function r(t,e){if(!t)throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called");return!e||"object"!=typeof e&&"function"!=typeof e?t:e}function i(t,e){if("function"!=typeof e&&null!==e)throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not "+typeof e);t.prototype=Object.create(e&&e.prototype,{constructor:{value:t,enumerable:!1,writable:!0,configurable:!0}}),e&&(Object.setPrototypeOf?Object.setPrototypeOf(t,e):t.__proto__=e)}function o(t,e){if(!(t instanceof e))throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function")}Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0});var u=n(1),s=function(){function t(e){o(this,t),this.value=e,this.init()}return t.prototype.init=function(){return this.bitmap=this.value.split("").map(function(){return 1}),this},t.prototype.render=function(){var t=this,e=arguments.length<=0||void 0===arguments[0]?[]:arguments[0],n=arguments.length<=1||void 0===arguments[1]?[]:arguments[1];return e.length?(0,u.mapString)(this.value,function(r,i){return n.indexOf(r)>-1?r:t.bitmap[i]?(0,u.sample)(e):r}):this.value},t.prototype.decay=function(){for(var t=arguments.length<=0||void 0===arguments[0]?1:arguments[0];t--;){var e=(0,u.getTruthyIndices)(this.bitmap);this.bitmap[(0,u.sample)(e)]=0}return this},t.prototype.text=function(){var t=arguments.length<=0||void 0===arguments[0]?this.value:arguments[0];return this.value=t,this.init(),this},t}(),c=function(t){function e(n){o(this,e);var i=r(this,t.call(this,n.textContent));return i.element=n,i}return i(e,t),e.prototype.write=function(t,e){return this.element.textContent=this.render(t,e),this},e}(s);e["default"]=function(t){return new c(t)}}])});
```

Comment: Try to add `defer` to your script to make it run when the DOM is ready: `<script src="skrypt.js" defer></script>`

Answer (score 1):

You can either create a page, which only does the loading screen, and then move onto another page with the element.
or otherwise give the loading screen an opaque background to hide the element, then hide it afterwards.

```js
document.getElementById("text").style.display = "none"; //Hide
document.getElementById("text").style.display = "none"; //Show
```

You can additionally defer the script via:

```html
<script src="script.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: thx, it's working :D

Comment: Happy to help ;), If you don't mind, please accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Well.. first of all, your text is black on a black background.. so it's never gonna appear unless you change that. :-) Secondly, you can add a function that will execute it after your loading ends called setTimeout, tag the p using query selector and apply the animation.

I changed the variable to timeLoading to track your intro, applied it in, and used that to change setTimeout.. with a change of -1000 to make it better (not sure why, the loading is kinda weird). The only thing that is wrong now is that at the beginning your text should be off screen.. but I'll leave that to you to practice. ;)

---

Here's the code you need:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        const text = baffle(".data");
        text.set({
            characters : '▒▓░ >▒█▓▒▒ >█▓▒░ ██▒ ▒█/▒░ ▓░>> <▒▓ █▒▓░ █▒▓▓',
            // szybkość, im większa tym wolniej
            speed: 69
        })
        text.start();
        //ilość znaków

        let timeLoading = 4000; // Set your intro loading here
        text.reveal(timeLoading);

        setTimeout(() => {
            document.querySelector("#text p").style.animation = "appear 2s";
        }, timeLoading - 1000);
    </script>
```